# Unexpected output while iterating over list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am printing the files name from current directory in my os .
files in my current directory are :test.py,Bob.txt,Alice.txt,

```
import os
files=os.listdir('.')
print(files)
#['test.py','Bob.txt','Alice.txt']
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        print(file)
    else:
        print(".txt no such file in this directory") 
        break
```

I am getting output **".txt no such file in this directory"**

but it should be print files name **Bob.txt** and **Alice.txt**
please explain why and how?

Comment: The `break` command will cause the loop to end. Removing it should give the desired output.

Comment: Get rid of the `break`; it's ending processing immediately after `test.py` is found not to end in `.txt`, so it never even tries to process `Bob.txt` or `Alice.txt`.

Comment: Also, note that it will print `".txt no such file in this directory"` anyway because of the .py present in the list

Comment: did bro and files name is printing but also printing no such file or directory if the filename not ends with .txt

Comment: What do you want to happen? This list has 2 txt files and one non-txt. Should it print two file names and "no such file"? Or should this case only print the two files?

Comment: then how to get rid of that ```no such file in this directory```  @buran

Comment: yes bro @tdelaney I want print only .txt files

Comment: Either remove the ‘print’ or remove ‘test.py’ from the list.

Answer (score 1):

With how you currently have your code structured, it will go to the else statement as soon as it encounters a *single* file that doesn't end with `.txt`. Since it seems like you want files that do end with `.txt`, it is possible to use list comprehension to quickly filter through the list.

```py
txtfiles = [file for file in files if file.endswith(".txt")]

if len(txtfiles) > 0:
    for file in txtfiles:
        print(file)
else:
    print(".txt no such file in this directory")
```

An alternative is to do the filtering manually within a for loop, only checking for an empty list at the end.

Comment: Your code is useful bro and Thank you for explainantion. you made my day....

Answer (score 1):

The if/else is run for each file in the list. As soon as you hit a non txt file, the else clause runs, prints the unwanted message and breaks out of the loop. Instead, you could track whether you've seen a txt file and print afterwards

```
import os
files=os.listdir('.')
print(files)
has_txt = False
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        has_txt = True
        print(file)
if not has_txt:
    print(".txt no such file in this directory")
```

But I think a list comprension to filter the directory list is the way to go.

```
import os
txt_files = [name for name in os.listdir('.') if name.endswith(".txt")]
if txt_files:
    print("\n".join(txt_files))
else:
    print(".txt no such file in this directory")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to check for `.txt` file recursively in the all the subdirectories then you can use os.walk

```
import os
path_of_directory = "."
flag = False
for directory, dir_names, files_in_dir in os.walk(path_of_directory):
    for each_file in files_in_dir:
        if os.path.splitext(each_file)[-1] == ".txt":
            print(each_file)
            flag = True

if not flag:
    print("No .txt file")
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look for [loop examples](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

The problem is `break` ends the loop

```
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        print(file)
    else:
        print(".txt no such file in this directory") 
        break
```

While it iterates the loop the first item is `test.py`

It does not match `.endswith(".txt")`, remove the `break` should work.

Comment: I want to print only txt files names bro

Comment: Oh sorry about that.
You may need to change your if condition to `not file.endswith(".txt")` and remove the else clause.